# Rails, PaperClip, S3, Heroku: Model icon fields not being saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am using Rails 3.2 + Heroku + S3 + Paperclip to store an icon on my `User` model. The model is not saving the 4 icon fields though. The images are getting processed and saved on S3 correctly and no errors are occurring. I also have another model that has a document being stored via Paperclip and S3. That model works perfectly in all cases. The `User` icon works locally but not on Heroku.

`production.rb` relevant configuration

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
}
```

User model code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :icon

  has_attached_file :icon, :url => "/system/:rails_env/:attachment/:style/:hash.:extension",
    :hash_data => ":class/:attachment/:id",
    :hash_secret => "superSecretThing",
    :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" },
    :default_url => "/blank.png"
  ...
```

Controller code: (This code is kind of crazy because I am AJAXing files Base64 encoded.)

```
  params[:user][:icon_data]
  decoded_file = Base64.decode64(data)
  begin
    split_name = params[:user][:icon_file_name].split(".")
    file = Tempfile.new([split_name[0..-2].join("."), ".#{split_name[-1]}"])
    file.binmode
    file.write(decoded_file)
    file.close
    @user.icon = open(file)
    @user.icon_file_name = params[:user][:icon_file_name]
  ensure
    file.unlink
  end
  @user.save
```

I do an almost identical process on another model with a Paperclip attachment and it works flawlessly. In both cases the attachment is being saved correctly to S3 and no errors are being raised. [This gist has example output](https://gist.github.com/4021058) for a controller action from the Heroku logs.

I am pretty baffled because the other model works fine. The only real difference is that the `User` attachment does image processing but that part appears to be working fine.

The problem is the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654111/paperclip-w-imagemagick-amazon-s3-and-heroku-imagemagick-s3-work-but-the?rq=1), but the solution there does not apply.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is that **not including the `:path` argument** makes it try to use the `:url` parameter for both the url and the path. The real fix is to include the `:path` parameter in addition to the url.

So for example a fixed configuration that works both locally and on Heroku:

```
has_attached_file :icon,
    :url => "/system/:rails_env/:attachment/:style/:hash.:extension",
    :path => "public/system/:rails_env/:attachment/:style/:hash.:extension",
    :hash_data => ":class/:attachment/:id",
    :hash_secret => "superDuperSecret",
    :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" },
    :default_url => "/blank.png"
```